# Ultra filter of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, filters

If $U$ is filter on set $X$ then $U$ is ultrafilter iff for $A \subseteq X$ always either $A \in U$ xor $A^c \in U$.

Is there corresponding property for ultra filter of closed sets? Also: is possible that $\bigcup_{i \in I}C_i$ in filter but no $C_i$ in filter? (for filter of closed set)

Comment: what is a filter of closed sets?

Comment: @CutieKrait: It’s a filter in the lattice of closed sets of a space: a family $\mathscr{F}$ of closed sets such that $H\cap K\in\mathscr{F}$ whenever $H,K\in\mathscr{F}$, and $H\in\mathscr{F}$ whenever $H\supseteq K\in\mathscr{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn’t any natural analogue of the complement property of ordinary ultrafilters. Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are disjoint closed sets in a $T_1$ space $X$. If $H\cup K\ne X$, the principal closed ultrafilter generated by any $x\in X\setminus(H\cup K)$ contains neither $H$ nor $K$. Thus, unless $H$ is clopen, there isn’t a closed $K$ disjoint from $H$ such that either $H$ or $K$ belongs to every closed ultrafilter on $X$.

The answer to the second question is obviously *yes* if the index set $I$ is allowed to be infinite, since a closed set is the union of singletons, so assume that $I$ is finite. In fact we may assume that $|I|=2$. Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter of closed sets in a space $X$, $H$ and $K$ are closed sets, and $H\cup K\in\mathscr{F}$. If $H\notin\mathscr{F}$, then there is an $F\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $H\cap F=\varnothing$. Then $$K\supseteq K\cap F=(H\cup K)\cap F\in\mathscr{F}\;,$$ so $K\in\mathscr{F}$. An easy induction shows that if $\mathscr{H}$ is a finite family of closed sets such that $\bigcup\mathscr{H}\in\mathscr{F}$, then $\mathscr{H}\cap\mathscr{F}\ne\varnothing$, just as with ordinary ultrafilters.

Comment: Why does $H \notin \mathscr F$ imply there is an $F \in \mathscr F$ such that $H \cap F = \varnothing$?

Comment: @dolan: Because $\mathscr{F}$ is an ultrafilter. If the closed set $H$ had non-empty intersection with each member of $\mathscr{F}$, it would have to belong to $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Why $X$ is a $T_1$ space and why $H,K$ are disjoint? I don't see where you use these assumptions.

Comment: @dolan: I need $X$ to be $T_1$ so that singletons are closed. In the first paragraph I was showing that there cannot be disjoint closed sets with a certain property, so I **assumed** that there were such sets and derived a contradiction: $H$ and $K$ were disjoint because I chose them to be disjoint.

Comment: But if $H$ and $K$ are not disjoint and $x \in X \setminus (H \cup K)$ then the principal ultrafilter generated by $x$ will not contain either $H$ or $K$ either. Then your argument works even if $H,K$ are not disjoint.

Comment: @dolan: You asked for an analogue of the fact that if $\mathscr{U}$ is an ordinary ultrafilter on $X$, then for any $A\subseteq X$ exactly one of $A$ and $X\setminus A$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$. Anything that I’d consider a reasonable analogue would involve disjoint sets, so was showing that no such analogue was possible. For that demonstration non-disjoint sets $H$ and $K$ are irrelevant.

Comment: Now I understand! Of course if $A$ is closed and not also open then $A^c$ not in $\mathscr F$. Therefore only possibility is to ask if there is closed set $K \subseteq A^c$ with either $K$ or $A$ in $\mathscr F$. You give counterexample to show that not even the weak statement is true.

Comment: @dolan: Yes, that’s exactly what I was trying to do.